# Upload MP4 as GIF (Like TenorGIF does) with Discord.py?

Tags: discord.py

I noticed that when you send a GIF from Tenor in Discord, it sends a `discord.Embed` that has an `EmbedProxy` which looks something like this: `EmbedProxy(url='https://media.tenor.co/videos/74b9d3ff72202514817a557c487a8115/mp4', width=640, height=480)`. Despite linking an mp4 file, Discord renders the file as a gif (no video player, autoplays the media). From what I've read, Discord/Tenor does this to save on storage as this is a much more efficient way to save gifs.

Is there a way to replicate this with discord.py? I have some 'gifs' in mp4 file format that I want to upload from my bot and be rendered as a gif.

Comment: Well you could do it by converting the mp4 to gif then doing that

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `file` KWARG that a `Messageable.send` can take in, this `file` KWARG takes in a `file` as you might've expected, here are the [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.abc.Messageable.send).